# Given a number, program to construct a two dimensional grid

Tags: java, arrays, grid, 2d, prime-factoring

The objective of the program is to create a 2D grid of values. We get the total number of elements to be present in the grid as input from the user (say, n). We need to construct a 2D grid of n values (these values are consecutive starting from 0 i.e., 0,1,2,3,4,5,6..n)

```
For n=9,

0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

For n=6,

Either,
0 1 2
3 4 5
or
0 1
2 3
4 5
```

Below is what i have managed until now:

```
int rowlen = (sqrt(n))
int collen = (n/rowlen)
int no = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rowlen-1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < collen-1) {

        System.out.print(no+"\t")
        no++;

    }

    System.out.println()
}
```

The above code works for perfect square numbers and for few other cases where 'n' is even.
But it fails if 'n' is odd and for few other even values of 'n' such as n=10.

Can you please suggest a better way of constructing the grid?

Answer (score 1):

[Prime factorization - for example: given `6`, finding `3*2` - is one of the great challenges of modern computing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) The simplest and probably the most reliable way to do it is just to iterate. (i.e. is it divisible by 1? is it divisible by 2? is it divisible by 3?...)

The good news is you're iterating anyways! So instead of trying to solve that problem by guessing factors (`rowlen` and `collen`) start iterating with output, and check every number along the way to see if it's a factor! Once you find one, only then should you bother deciding how many rows and columns you will have.

Something like (pseudo-code):

```
var n = 10;

var cols = 0;

for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(i>1 && ((cols === 0 && n%i === 0) || (cols>0 && i%cols===0))) {
        if(cols===0) { // we've found our first prime factor;
                       // this value will be used as the number of columns
            cols = i;
        }
        print("\n");
    }
    print(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard JP Le Guen, your idea gave me a direction. I'm currently going thro' the link you gave. Meanwhile, I replicated the code snippet you provided in java and got an arithmetic exception due to the below line: if(i>1 && (n%i === 0 || i%cols===0)) since cols = 0 for i=2 or more, i%cols gives the exception.

Comment: Uhhhh I don't see your "below line" :P

Comment: Also, unless you're a graduate level compsci or math student, I don't suggest combing through the Wikipedia page on prime factorization. I don't prohibit you either; I encourage you to follow your curiosity... but be warned it might not be useful - if you could crack the problem you'd either be rich overnight or murdered by spies in your sleep :P

Comment: Yeah, Sorry I pressed the enter key before pasting the line :)

Comment: Hmmm, ya, it makes sense that line gives an error; I first wrote the code in JavaScript. You'll just have to add another `if` clause. I'll try and update the snippet.

Comment: You are absolutely right! :) but the shameful factor is i'm a CS masters student and still I'm unable to understand the concept of prime factorization :|

Comment: "Also, unless you're a graduate level compsci or math student, I don't suggest combing through the Wikipedia page on prime factorization." Lol too late.

Comment: Noooo! I never should have linked to it! :P @user1647965 I modified the pseudo code... not very cleanly... but it should work.